Liquibase standalone --log-level=INFO duplicates logs
I'm running liquibase as initContainer for my service.
      initContainers:
        - name: liquibase
          image: docker.io/liquibase/liquibase:4.27.0
          command:
            - "liquibase"
            - "update"
            - "--changeLogFile=db/changelog/db.changelog-root.xml"
            - "--url=$(LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_URL)"
            - "--username=$(LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_USERNAME)"
            - "--password=$(LIQUIBASE_COMMAND_PASSWORD)"
            - "--log-level=INFO"

I've noticed that setting the log level to INFO causes the log statements to be "duplicated".
Liquibase Version: 4.27.0
[2024-10-25 08:46:57] INFO [liquibase.ui] Liquibase Version: 4.27.0
Liquibase Open Source 4.27.0 by Liquibase
[2024-10-25 08:46:57] INFO [liquibase.ui] Liquibase Open Source 4.27.0 by Liquibase

My assumption is that there's multiple loggers or appenders or something like an issue with additivity.
I've checked the Liquibase docs but I didn't manage to find anything related to the issue.
Is there any way to prevent the log statements from showing up twice but still have INFO log level?
